# Creating and passing multiple pthreads in C

Tags: c, pthreads

I'm trying to get pthread to output a variable declared in a for loop:

```
pthread_t pthread[10];

void * count(void* argv){
    int index = *(int*)argv;
    printf("%d", index);
    pthread_exit(NULL);
}

int main() {
     for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
        pthread_create(&pthread[i], NULL, count,(void*)&i);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Output I thought:

> 0123456789 (or not in order, but all 10 number)

What I got:

> 123456789

Why 0 is not in here?

Comment: You can't rely on this working anyway: `pthread[i]` may not start executing until after `i` has been changed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One problem is that your `main()` thread exits without waiting for the child threads to finish, which means the child threads may not have time to finish (or potentially even begin) their execution before the process is terminated.

To avoid that problem, you need to call `pthread_join()` on all of your threads before `main()` exits, like this:

```
int main() {
     for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
        pthread_create(&pthread[i], NULL, count,(void*)&i);
     }
     for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
        pthread_join(pthread[i], NULL);  // won't return until thread has exited
     }
    return 0;
}
```

The other problem, as mentioned by 500 in the comments, is that you are passing a pointer to `i` to the child threads, which they then dereference, and since `i` is being modified in the main thread's loop, it's undefined behavior what value the child threads will read from that pointer.  One way to avoid this is to give each thread its own separate (non-changing) integer to read:

```
 int values[10];

 for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
    values[i] = i;
    pthread_create(&pthread[i], NULL, count,(void*)&values[i]);
 }
```

Comment: 'you could call pthread_join() on all of your threads before main() exits, or use some other mechanism to prevent main() returning before you want it to'

Comment: @MartinJames I'm not sure there is any other mechanism that will work reliably, if only because the pthreads library contains thread-shutdown/resource-cleanup code that executes *after the thread's user-visible function has returned*.  That means that any synchronization mechanism that you manually implemented inside the user-visible thread function itself will necessarily introduce a race condition, because it can't guarantee that pthreads' post-user-function cleanup code will finish executing "quickly enough" to avoid getting stepped on by the resource cleanup code of the main() thread.